# Add spacing between the nav bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

how do I put the reserved on the left side and the footer on right side of the footer and add space between links on CSS? without using flexbox

HTML:

```
    <footer>
            <div id="reserved">All rights reserved</div>
            <nav id="footer">
                <a href="">Home</a>
                <a href="">About</a>
                <a href="">Opportunities</a>
                <a href="">Terms</a>
            </nav>
    </footer>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why 'without using flexbox' ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `float` this will give what you want. If you don't want `flexbox`

```css
#reserved {
  float: left;
}

#footer {
  float: right;
}

#footer a {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

footer::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="reserved">All rights reserved</div>
  <nav id="footer">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Opportunities</a>
    <a href="">Terms</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: Just edited the question, i'm not allowed to use flexbox

Comment: Out of curiosity (nothing more) may I ask why not?

Comment: we're only allowed to use basic styling

Comment: Yes, I understand. But why? Is it because you have to support IE11? See: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @batgerel.e please include the suggested code within your answer, codepen links can break and become useless to future users

Answer (score 0):

For layouts like this, floats can come in pretty handy.
Define #reserved to float left, and #footer to float right. This will place both child elements on opposite ends.
You can simply add a margin to your anchor tags to your desired size:

```css
#reserved {
  float:left;
}

#footer {
  float:right;
}

#footer>a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="reserved">All rights reserved</div>
  <nav id="footer">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Opportunities</a>
    <a href="">Terms</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you want your links to be displayed; if you want them to be displayed downwards, then use block, otherwise you don't really need to add much code except to display the ids inline-block and add some padding to the nav a links.

The snippet below shows an example of displaying the menu downwards. I added a `vertical-align:top` so that the "All rights reserved" would be inline with the top menu link (as opposed to displaying at the bottom of the menu. Adjust as you see fit.

```css
#reserved,
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#reserved {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

nav {
  left: 50%;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="reserved">All rights reserved</div>
  <nav id="footer">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Opportunities</a>
    <a href="">Terms</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just put a style on the footer

```
#footer{
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

In this example, it will give a space of 10px, both on left and right side.

But when you want #reserved to be on the right and #footer to the left, then enclose it both with div having this css

```
#wrapper{
display:flex;
}

#reserved{
flex: 1 1;
}

#footer{
flex: 1 1;
}
```

Then, do this:

```
<footer id="wrapper">
            <div id="reserved">All rights reserved</div>
            <nav id="footer">
                <a href="">Home</a>
                <a href="">About</a>
                <a href="">Opportunities</a>
                <a href="">Terms</a>
            </nav>
    </footer>
```

Comment: He wants `#reserved` to left and `#footer` to right. Above example just giving padding to `#footer`.